# How to convert 32bit wav file in a numpy array to a 24bit wav file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, audio

I would like to convert a 32-bit wav numpy array to a 24-bit wav numpy array using python3 and the numpy library.

I am reading the file like this:

```
import numpy as np
    sample_rate, file_info = read(filepath)
    np_array = np.array(file_info)
```

Now based on the dtype which can be extracted via
something like this

```
if (str(np_array.dtype) == 'int32'):
```

I would like to retranscode the np_array to become a 24bit array.
I need to do this for analysis purposes. The goal is - not to generate a new file.

Any hints in how to do this effectively?

Thank you

Comment: You say you want a file several times throughout, and then at the end you say you don't need a file. `numpy` doesn't have a 24-bit type, so it's not clear what you want by a 24-bit wave file if it's not a file to store on disk.

Comment: You are right. I should have specified that Id like to convert a 32bit digital array representation into a 24bit digital array representation. - Currently I am exploring the option of importing sox - and using the convert() function.

Comment: allocate a new 24 bit array ... iterate across the 32 bit array ... inside the loop do a bit shift to the right to discard the lowest order byte of the current index array element ...  then save this new 24 bit value into the matching index of the 24 bit array

Comment: @DeltaFi It is quite unclear what exactly you want to do, but probably this gives you some clues: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

```
import sox

 

transformer = sox.Transformer()
transformer.convert(samplerate=sample_rate, bitdepth=16)
sox_array = transformer.build_array(sample_rate_in=sample_rate, input_array=np_array)
```

This will convert the array to 16bit, which allows for analysis workflows, which will always be the same.

Comment: I appreciate you writing the answer, but this isn't 24bit which is what you asked for.  I'm curious about this, so could you explain in your answer why a 16bit array works for you but a 32bit one doesn't. Also, if you want, why you needed to go through sox to get this rather than numpy.

Comment: I needed a standardized way to convert various bit-depths to a standardized bit-depth. It could have been any. I chose 32bit when starting the thread, as I was not aware that 32bit conversion was not supported.